# Getting java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn. Thoughts?

Tags: clojure

Folks, I have the below function but I'm getting a java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn" error when I run. Any thoughts on how to fix it?

```
(defn tickets [price] (fn [price] ((and proms/med-to-high?
                                           (partial checks/price-matches? price)))))
```

I am trying to use the above function in the below function. What I want to do is to check if a ticket is at a specific price and if not, print the ticket was not

```
(defn right-tickets?
 "Returns true for right ticket.Else, print something"
  [price]
  (if (tickets? price) true (do (println "Ticket not at right price") false)))
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
((and proms/med-to-high?
 (partial checks/price-matches? price))
```

There is your problem.  You evaluate the `and` expression, and then you try to treat the resulting boolean like a function.  Try removing the outer parentheses from that expression.

Comment: Made the correction but did not seem to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the error that [@user100464](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26101886/1562315) points out,

- there is too much global state
- you are mixing computation with reporting.

But first, you call function `tickets?`, having defined one with the different name of `tickets`. Let's go for the latter.

In `tickets`, `proms/med-to-high?` appears to be global data. I guess from the wording that it applies to some event, which also has some ticket prices attached. We can represent the event data as a map, say

```
{:prom :low, :prices #{10.50 15.00 25.00}}
```

Then your `tickets` function can be

```
(defn tickets [event price]
  (and (#{:medium :high} (:prom event)) ((:prices event) price)))
```

For instances,

```
(tickets {:prom :low, :prices #{10.50 15.00 25.00}} 15.0)
;nil

(tickets {:prom :medium, :prices #{10.50 15.00 25.00}} 10.0)
;nil

(tickets {:prom :medium, :prices #{10.50 15.00 25.00}} 15.0)
;15.0
```

But if I am prepared to spend £20 on a ticket, then one at £10 is fine. So I want to see the *range* of qualifying prices:

```
(defn tickets [event price]
  (and
    (#{:medium :high} (:prom event))
    (seq (filter (partial >= price) (:prices event)))))
```

For instances,

```
(tickets {:prom :medium, :prices #{10.50 15.00 25.00}} 10.0)
;nil

(tickets {:prom :medium, :prices #{10.50 15.00 25.00}} 20.0)
;(10.5 15.0)
```

It might be that the prices were a map, giving the number of tickets at each price ... and so on.

The ticket message function can be

```
(def ticket-message {nil "No tickets at the price"})
```

Which, applied to `nil`, yields the message, but applied to anything else, yields `nil`.